# SignalR Android Hubconnection can't start if already connected

Tags: android, signalr

I'm working in SignalR implementation in Android. 
In the first Step, its connected easily. And after reopen app its crashed with logged error .. Hub connection is already connected

```
 Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        mInstance.setmHubConnection(getApplicationContext());
        mInstance.setHubProxy();
        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mInstance.mHubConnection.getLogger());
        signalRFuture = mInstance.mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);
        try {
            signalRFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            SharedPrefUtil.clearAllSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.wrong_server), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("SimpleSignalR", e.toString());
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using mHubConnection.disconnect(); when app getting destroyed?

Comment: Yes i'm using Destroyed method but its not invoking when i'm minimizing or closed the App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all as you described your  concern . That on first approach your SignalR hubconnection is started and when you relaunch your app its gonna crashed. So MAke sure whenever you trying to connect SignalR hubconnection you should check whether its connected or disconnected. using following code .

Hope it will work. Good luck.

```
  mHubConnection.stop();
```